# Tkinter and Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

i am kind of new to python and i wrote a client server based program. my client side is using Tkinter for GUI and when the program enters the function that communicates with the server and runs the whole program the GUI freezes. I basically know why this happens but i have no idea how to fix it in my specific program..

```
from Tkinter import *
import re
import os
import socket
import os.path
import time

MAXSIZE=5000000000 # bigest file u can send

class Application(Frame):

    gateway =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.creat_widgets()

    def creat_widgets(self):

        self.instruction1 = Label(self,text = "Enter IP Address:")
        self.instruction1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.ipEntry = Entry(self)
        self.ipEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W + E)

        self.instruction2 = Label(self, text = "Enter PORT:")
        self.instruction2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.portEntry = Entry(self)
        self.portEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W + E)

        self.instruction3 = Label(self,text = "Enter Path:")
        self.instruction3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.pathEntry = Entry(self)
        self.pathEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W + E)


        self.send_button = Button(self, text = "Send File" ,command = self.send_data)
        self.send_button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)


        self.inbox = Text(self, width = 40, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.inbox.grid(row =5,column = 0 , columnspan= 3)

    def send_data(self):
        content = self.ipEntry.get()
        if(re.match("^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$",content)):
            self.ip = content
        else:
            self.ip = False
        content = self.portEntry.get()
        if(re.match("^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$",content)):
            self.port = content
        else:
            self.port = False
        content = self.pathEntry.get()
        if os.path.exists(content):
            self.path = content
        else:
            self.path = False

        if (self.ip and self.port and self.path):
            self.connect()
            if os.path.getsize(self.path)<=MAXSIZE:
                self.update_text("Sending File......")
                self.sendFile()
            else:
                self.update_text("FILE IS TOO BIG (MAX SIZE IS 500MB)")
        else:
            self.update_text("Error with entrys")



    def connect(self): 
        try:
            self.gateway.connect((self.ip, int(self.port)))
        except socket.error, msg:
            message =  'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
            self.update_text(message)



    def sendFile(self):#send the file in the path entered
        self.update_text("Sending File......")
        tail = os.path.split(self.path)#get the files name and extention and send it to server.
        self.gateway.sendall(tail[1])
        self.sendLen()
        try:
            with open(str(self.path), 'rb') as f:
                    data = f.read()
                    self.gateway.sendall(data)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        if self.chkProt(self.gateway.recv(10)):
            self.update_text("DONE!")



    def sendLen(self):#Function that handles the the sending of the length of the file.
        flen=os.path.getsize(str(self.path))
        self.gateway.sendall(str(flen))
        while self.chkProt(self.gateway.recv(10))==False:#checks that the length has been sent and received properly and no problems occurred.
            self.gateway.sendall(str(flen))  #resend file length if a problem occurred.


    def chkProt(self,num):#received a protocol that the server sent and act accordingly.
        if num=="101":
            return True
        if num=="102":
            print "AN ERROR HAS OCCURED"
            return False
        elif num=="103":
            return False



    def update_text(self, Etext):
      #  self.inbox.delete(0.0, END)
        self.inbox.insert(0.0, Etext)


root = Tk()
root.title("HCFF")
root.geometry("300x200")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You say you know why the program freezes, but don't know how to fix it. It actually seems like you do have some idea of how to fix it, since its in the thread title and tags (threading). Have you tried using the `threading` module to address the issue?

Comment: I have tried using multithreading but my knowledge is pretty basic in this topic and i have no idea how to aplly threading in my specific program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid freezing interface, you can run you `send_data` function in separate thread (using [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module). Simply import it and change one line inside `create_widgets` function:

```
import threading

...

def creat_widgets(self):
    ....
    self.send_button = Button(self, text = "Send File", command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.send_data).start())
```